# Convert r plot with log axis to log 2 axis

Tags: r

I have the following r code:

```
x <- readClipboard()
> plot(x)
> myData = x
> myResult = ecdf(myData)

> myResult
Empirical CDF 
Call: ecdf(myData)
 x[1:200] = -0.031027, -0.13797, -0.16993,  ..., 0.016108, 0.60295
> plot(myResult, xlim=c(0,1e1), log="x")
```

Which results in a log-based axis. However, the x axis is log 10 based. How do I convert it to log base 2?

I have tried the following options:
On the basis of:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10
base <- 2
plot(x,y,axes=FALSE)
axis(1,at=x,labels = base^(x))
axis(2,at=y)
```

I did:

```
 base <- 2
> plot(myResult,y,axes=FALSE)
> plot(myResult,axes=FALSE)
> axis(1,at=x,labels = base^(x))
Error in base^(x) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> axis(1,at=myResult,labels = base^(myResult))
Error in base^(myResult) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I've also unsuccessfully attempted to do this via magicaxis:

```
magaxis(magaxis(unlog='x'), powbase=2)
Error in axis(side = list(family = "sans"), at = c(-0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4,  : 
  invalid axis number -2147483648
> magaxis((unlog='x'), powbase=2)
Error in axis(side = "x", at = c(-0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.2),  : 
  invalid axis number -2147483648
In addition: Warning message:
In axis(side = "x", at = c(-0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.2),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
> plot(myResult)
> magaxis((unlog='x'), powbase=2)
Error in axis(side = "x", at = c(-0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.2),  : 
  invalid axis number -2147483648
In addition: Warning message:
In axis(side = "x", at = c(-0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.2),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796231/how-make-the-x-axis-a-base-2-logarithm-in-r-with-magicaxis

Comment: I get the following errors: Error in base^(x) : > axis(1,at=x,labels = base^(x))
Error in base^(x) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> axis(1,at=myResult,labels = base^(myResult))
Error in base^(myResult) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
>

Comment: edit your question. Indicate that you tried (what you have tried based on the link I provided) and also include the error that you got.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier using `ggplot2` and `scales` packages.

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = VARX, y = VARY)) + geom_point() + scale_y_continuous(trans = log2_trans())
```

Comment: I get the following error: Error in log2_trans() : could not find function "log2_trans"

Comment: have you installed and loaded package `scales`?